# How can I transform dates expressed with month names to numerical month designations?

Tags: text-processing, date, macos

I use MacOS and I have variable `date` in format

```
3.Jan.2023,
12.Nov.2017,
9.Apr.2022,
...
```

I need to change in

```
03.01.2023,
12.11.2017,
09.04.2022,
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MacOS [`date`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/date/) allows you specify input and output formats for conversions:

```
for inp in "3.Jan.2023" "12.Nov.2017" "9.Apr.2022"; do
    date -j -f "%d.%b.%Y" "$inp" "+%d.%m.%Y"
done
```

According to [`strptime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strptime.html):

- `%b` The month, using the locale's month names; either the abbreviated or full name may be specified.
- `%d` The day of the month [01,31]; leading zeros are permitted but not required.
- `%m` The month number [01,12]; leading zeros are permitted but not required.
- `%Y` The year, including the century (for example, 1988).

Output:

```
03.01.2023
12.11.2017
09.04.2022
```

Comment: Note that "locale's month names" means that modifying the locale prior to executing the command depending on whether the source of the dates used the same locale as the current one.

Answer (score 6):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    {
        split($1,d,".")
        $1 = sprintf("%02d.%02d.%04d", d[1], index("  JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",d[2])/3, d[3])
        print
    }
' file
03.01.2023,
12.11.2017,
09.04.2022,
```

That's 2 blanks before `Jan`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk` to convert from one format to the other:

```
awk -F. '
    BEGIN { m["Jan"]=1; m["Feb"]=2; m["Mar"]=3; m["Dec"]=12 }
    { printf "%02d.%02d.%04d,\n", $1, m[$2], $3 }
' file
```

The `BEGIN` line needs to be completed to follow the pattern for all months.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input file could be interpreted as a header-less CSV data set, we may read it with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) and rewrite the first field of each record with the reformatted date.

We may use `strptime()` to parse the existing datestamp into a Unix timestamp representation. We may then pass that timestamp straight to `strftime()` to present it in the wanted format.

In other words,

```bash
mlr --csv -N put '$1 = strftime(strptime($1, "%e.%b.%Y"), "%d.%m.%Y")' file
```

Here, `put` is the Miller sub-command for applying custom operations on the record stream, and `$1` is the first field of the current record. The format string argument to `strptime()`, `%e.%b.%Y`, describes how the datestamp in the input should be parsed. The `%b` format is locale-dependent and will affect how the abbreviated month names are interpreted. Likewise, the format string argument to `strftime()`, `%d.%m.%Y`, describes how we want to format the Unix timestamp that `strptime()` outputs.

See the manual for the `strftime` library function on your system for further information about these format strings (`man stftime`).

The output, given the input in the question, would be

```
03.01.2023,
12.11.2017,
09.04.2022,
```

A macOS user may install Miller using e.g. Homebrew:

```bash
brew install miller
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 'my %months = [Z=>] <Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec>, 1..12; \ 
             s/ <( (\d**1..2) \. (<alpha>**3) )> \. \d**4 \, /{sprintf q[%02d.%02d], $0, %months{$1}}/;'  file 

#OR

~$ raku -pe 'my %months = [Z=>] <Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec>, 1..12; \ 
             s[ <( (\d**1..2) \. (<alpha>**3) )> \. \d**4 \, ] = "{sprintf q[%02d.%02d], $0, %months{$1}}";'  file
```

OR:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my %months = [Z=>] <Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec>, 1..12; \
            put S/ <( (\d**1..2) \. (<alpha>**3) )> \. \d**4 \, /{sprintf q[%02d.%02d], $0, %months{$1} }/ for lines();' file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'my %months = [Z=>] <Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec>, 1..12; \
            put S[ <( (\d**1..2) \. (<alpha>**3) )> \. \d**4 \, ] = "{sprintf q[%02d.%02d], $0, %months{$1} }" for lines();'  file
```

Briefly, you can use Raku to swap out string months and replace with numeric (Integer). Days can be formatted as well (with `sprintf`). Declare a hash `%months` which has 3-letter month names as key, assigning the numbers `1..12` as value. The `[Z=>]` reduction metaoperator pulls successive elements off the two lists given to it, and pairs them as `key => value`. The result is such that `say %months.sort(*.value);` returns the following:

```
(Jan => 1 Feb => 2 Mar => 3 Apr => 4 May => 5 Jun => 6 Jul => 7 Aug => 8 Sep => 9 Oct => 10 Nov => 11 Dec => 12)
```

Once you have the `%months` hash, it's a simple `s///` substitution (or `S///` substitution, as the case may be). In the first two code examples, the `-pe` autoprinting flags are used. The match in the left-half of the `s///` recognizes all elements, but the `<(`...`)>` ["Capture Markers"](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#index-entry-regex_%3C(_)%3E-Capture_markers:_%3C(_)%3E) drop everything outside, so that only the day and string month are captured (day into `$0`; month into `$1`). In the right half of the `s///` operator, the `%months` hash is fed the `$1` variable key like so: `%months{$1}`, which tells the hash to return the key's `value`. In the output both day and month are formatted with `sprintf`.

The third and fourth code examples are similar to the first, except that the `%months` hash is only declared once. Instead of `-pe` or `-ne` command-line flags, the lines are looped through using `for lines()`. Finally, Raku takes care not to over-write immutable strings, so the `S///` capital-S form is used to [*return the resultant string*](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-S$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS_non-destructive_substitution).

Sample Output (all code examples):

```
03.01.2023,
12.11.2017,
09.04.2022,
```

https://raku.org